# Разбор работы setInteraval()

Tags: javascript

```
        var previousTime = 0,
        INTERVAL = 30,
        W = 800,
        H = 600,
        avatar,
        LEFT = 37, UP = 38, RIGHT = 39, DOWN = 40;

    window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            c = canvas.getContext("2d"); // 2x мерный поток
            console.log(c);
            avatar = new Avatar();
            /*avatar.x = (W - avatar.size) / 2;
            avatar.y = (H - avatar.size) / 2;*/



        setInterval(function() {
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime(),
                timeElapsed;

            if (previouseTime = 0) {
                previouseTime = currentTime;
            }

            timeElapsed = previouseTime - currentTime;
            update(timeElapsed, currentTime);
            draw(canvas, timeElapsed, currentTime);

            previouseTime = currentTime;

        }, INTERVAL);
    };
```

Доброго времени суток. Разбираю игру написанную на языке JS. После функции setInterval идет еще код, но он не важен т.к. не касается моего вопроса в принципе. Вопрос состоит в том, что функция setInterval  запускается каждый раз через промежуток времени INTERVAL, обрабатывая функции update и draw, даже если мы не совершаем не каких действий в игре(к примеру движение персонажа в разные стороны)? То есть по сути у нас постоянно работающий код? 
Спасибо за заранее предоставленную помощь.

Comment: И да! Весь код после идет уже не в теле  window.onload = function()..., а после него.